# matplotlib animation for synchronized movement of multiple shapes in a single figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have to animate two objects together as an unit. One object is rectangle and other object is many arcs together as a fountain starting from the cneter point of rectangle. I have created a function for plotting the arcs through the center of rectangle as shown. 
[image: A rectangle with many arcs]

***Problem Description :*** I want to animate this combined image (Rectangle + Bunch of arcs together) and make it look progressing ahead for every time step. For this, I have created a function with matplotlib animate. The rectangle as a seperate animates perfectly. Where as the arcs does not move ahead along with the rectangle when animated.

***Current Output:*** Either only rectangle moves or only one arc out of the bunch of arcs moves in my animation. I am unable to figure out what am I doing wrong.

***Expected Output :*** Could someone please suggest me how can I animate all these objects(in figure) and make them move ahead? Am I doing something wrong by taking two different shapes in two animate functions?

My code snippet for animation function :

```
class collusionAnimation():
    def initVehicle(self):
        x_lim = np.array(axes.set_xlim(-30,30))
        y_lim = np.array(axes.set_ylim(-30,30))
        OrientRad = self.orient * 3.142 / 180
        RotWidth_HalfX = ((self.vehicleWidth / 2) * math.cos( OrientRad )) - ((self.vehicleLength / 2) * math.sin( OrientRad ))
        Rotheight_HalfY = ((self.vehicleLength / 2) * math.cos( OrientRad )) + ((self.vehicleWidth / 2) * math.sin( OrientRad ))
        self.rect = plt.Rectangle( (self.InitPosX - RotWidth_HalfX , self.InitPosY - Rotheight_HalfY), self.vehicleWidth, self.vehicleLength, angle=self.orient, color='k', alpha=0.3 )
        ax.add_patch(self.rect)
        return self.rect,

    def initTraj(self):
        x_lim = np.array( axes.set_xlim( -30, 30 ) )
        y_lim = np.array( axes.set_ylim( -30, 30 ) )
        #self.InitPosX = 0
        #self.InitPosY = 0
        steer = []
        steer = self.__steeringArcDraw( self.InitPosX, self.InitPosY )
        return steer

    def animateCollusion(self, i):
        #self.rect.set_width( 1.2 )
        #self.rect.set_height( 1.0 )
        self.InitPosX = self.InitPosX + 0.5
        self.InitPosY = self.InitPosY + 0.5
        self.rect.set_xy([self.InitPosX, self.InitPosY])
        ax.add_patch( self.rect )
        return self.rect,

    def animatetrajectory(self, i):
        self.InitPosX = self.InitPosX + 0.5
        self.InitPosY = self.InitPosY + 0.5
        steer = self.__steeringArcDraw( self.InitPosX, self.InitPosY )
        return steer


    c1 = collusionAnimation(4,2,(0,0),-45,[90])
    wm = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    wm.window.state('zoomed')



    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, c1.animateCollusion,init_func=c1.initVehicle,frames=50,interval=1000,blit=False,repeat=False)
    animTraj = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, c1.animatetrajectory,init_func=c1.initTraj,frames=50,interval=1000, blit=True,repeat=False)

    plt.show()
```

> *Here, the function "__steeringArcDraw" draws the bunch of arcs to the rectangle.*

***Solutions Tried :***

> I have also tried to implement both the animate functions into a
>   single one.

```
def initVehicle(self):
        x_lim = np.array(axes.set_xlim(-30,30))
        y_lim = np.array(axes.set_ylim(-30,30))
        OrientRad = self.orient * 3.142 / 180
        RotWidth_HalfX = ((self.vehicleWidth / 2) * math.cos( OrientRad )) - ((self.vehicleLength / 2) * math.sin( OrientRad ))
        Rotheight_HalfY = ((self.vehicleLength / 2) * math.cos( OrientRad )) + ((self.vehicleWidth / 2) * math.sin( OrientRad ))
        self.rect = plt.Rectangle( (self.InitPosX - RotWidth_HalfX , self.InitPosY - Rotheight_HalfY), self.vehicleWidth, self.vehicleLength, angle=self.orient, color='k', alpha=0.3 )
        ax.add_patch(self.rect)
        steer = self.__steeringArcDraw( self.InitPosX, self.InitPosY )
        return self.rect, steer 

    def animateCollusion(self, i):
        #self.rect.set_width( 1.2 )
        #self.rect.set_height( 1.0 )
        self.InitPosX = self.InitPosX + 0.5
        self.InitPosY = self.InitPosY + 0.5
        self.rect.set_xy([self.InitPosX, self.InitPosY])
        ax.add_patch( self.rect )
        steer =self.__steeringArcDraw(self.InitPosX, self.InitPosY)
        return self.rect, steer 

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, c1.animateCollusion,init_func=c1.initVehicle,frames=50,interval=1000,blit=False,repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

> But I can see only Rectangle progressing for every frame and no arcs at all. Also, this fails to run when I make Blit to be true. Hence I chose to make two animate functions each, one for rectangle movement and other for bunch of arcs movement.

Comment: There is a lot going on here, and I did not carefully check everything; but in general, you need *one* `FuncAnimation` instance, and *one* animating function. This function should return a list of all artists you want to update.

Comment: Thanks. It is one of the methods that I have already tried. But unfortunately, it did not yield me any positive results as stated above. But I appreciate your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like what you return is not a sequence of artists `(artist1, artist2, artist3)`, but more something like `(artist1, (artist2, artist3))`